# Joining consecutive commas using ex-mode

Tags: substitute, ex-mode, global-command

I have a large list of scores that looks likes this:

```
Michelle
,46419
,32413
Frank
,46412
,33810
Steve
,28333
,17830
,37
Joe
,136
,93
Alicia
,121300
,84146
```

How can I move my list in Vim so it is re-arranged like this:

```
Michelle,46419,32413
Frank,46412,33810
Steve,28333,17830,37
Joe,136,93
Alicia,121300,84146
```

I've tried altering the list with this formula

```
:g/^,/s/$\n//g
```

But this doesn't get the lines with commas to fall in line behind the one ones without.

Comment: Not after the words, that was offered by Stackoverflow as a way to show a carriage return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a simple substitute command. Try this:

```
:%s/\n,/,
```

This removes a newline from every line containing a newline followed by a comma.  You could also do it like this:

```
:%s/\n\ze,
```

The way this works is by marking the end of the selection to be removed, and the only text that will be removed is what matches before `\ze`. From `:h /\ze`

```
                                                        */\ze*
\ze Matches at any position, and sets the end of the match there: The
        previous char is the last char of the whole match. |/zero-width|
        Can be used multiple times, the last one encountered in a matching
        branch is used.
        Example: "end\ze\(if\|for\)" matches the "end" in "endif" and
        "endfor".
        This cannot be followed by a multi. |E888|
        {not in Vi} {not available when compiled without the |+syntax| feature}
```

Answer (score 4):

@DJMcMayhem's solution is pretty good but Vim is pretty powerful so here is an alternative with the global command:

```
:g/^,/normal! kJ
```

That you can translate as "For every line which begins by a comma use the normal mode keys <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> i.e. to go the upper line and join it with the next one".

**Edit** As @Christian Brabandt said in the comments you can also use `gJ` which doesn't insert or remove any spaces, while `J` will remove indent and insert up to two spaces:

```
:g/^,/normal! kgJ
```

Finally to avoid using normal mode and shorten the command you could use the `:join` command (shortened to `:j`) with the range `-1`:

```
:g/^,/-1j
```

See [`:h J`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#J), [`:h gJ`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gJ) and [`:h :j`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:j)

Comment: also see the gJ command